# Presenting Main View Controller from a Child View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a main view controller and am presenting a child view. For one of the settings inside the child, I need to call the main view controller again. It would just make things a lot easier.

The following causes a hierarchy problem:

```
#define appDelegate (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

[self presentViewController:[appDelegate mainViewController] animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Is there any way to call the mainViewController easily while not losing the state of the child view?

**EDIT**

Here is how I'm presenting the child view.

```
ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childViewController];
[childViewController release];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
[navigationController release];
```

Comment: Can't you just create a new parentView and push it to the child?

Comment: @KassemBagher Yes, this is an option, this would just be very very inconvenient since there is so much initialization that needs to take place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't present a view controller that has already been presented or is in a navigation stack.  What is the mainViewController? Did you instantiate it? Has it been added to the screen yet?

If yes to both, you either need to back into it (dismiss to it) or remove it from it's parent first and then present it.

Comment: The answer to both is yes. I've updated my question to show how I'm calling the child. What would be the easiest way to solve my problem?

Comment: What are you doing with mainViewController?

Comment: Okay, what I ended up doing was saving the instance of the child view with a property set to `(nonatomic, retain)`, then dismissed it to get back to the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

In your child view, you should have access to your application delegate and its mainViewController property, like this:

```
    MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this but am getting an error at the `presentViewController` line.

Comment: Can you get the stack trace? Let's see what it doesn't like.